# Fuzzy Search in File content

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, search, csom

My scenario : I am testing the search engine in SharePoint 2019 server. What i found out is that fuzzy search works in this way WORD then after i can place an asterisk(WORD*).

What i am trying to figure out if try to find the word SharePoint in a file it returns me only the files having exact match. I have entered the word SharePooint in a docx file and manually forced indexing. What i want want now is if i search for SharePoint, the file having SharePooint should also be returned.

Can you guys point me out how to do this? This is the first step am testing directly on SharePoint eventually i will build a c# app to use this.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for SharePo* and then will return SharePoint and SharePooint or you could create thesaurus and import in SharePoint Server

Create and deploy a thesaurus in SharePoint Server
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/create-and-import-a-thesaurus